# EventArgs has always the same value when trying to pass parameters to event handler

Tags: c#, .net, webmethod

I want to pass parameters to the event handler of a web method. I added an auto-unsubscription logic to avoid that the event handler gets fired multiple times. The problem is that I always get the same instance of the EventArgs object in the event handling method.

ie: If I call GetInfo 3 times with 3 different values for infoVersion, the event handling function gets fired 3 times but I will always get the same instance of the variable e.

```
public void GetInfo(int infoVersion)
{
      System.EventHandler<ServiceReference.getInfoCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            client.getInfoCompleted -= handler;
            client_getInfoCompleted(sender, e, infoVersion);
        };

        client.getInfoCompleted += handler;
        client.getInfoAsync(infoVersion);

}

void client_getInfoCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.getInfoCompletedEventArgs e, int infoVersion)
{
    //do something with e.result and infoVersion
    //e.result is always the same but infoVersion is correct
}
```

EDIT: The web method has been tested and works fine. The e.result shall change if I modify the infoVersion value.

If I use a more simple approach like below, e.result will be different each time:

```
public void GetInfo(int infoVersion)
{
    client.getInfoCompleted += client_getInfoCompleted;
    client.getInfoAsync(infoVersion);
}

void client_getInfoCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.getInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //e.result has a different value each time.
}
```

Comment: So the request data (infoVersion) is always correct. Are you sure the result is supposed to be different for different versions? did you test that?

Comment: Well, why not?  The real code that matters here of course is the code that fires the event.  There is no rule that says that it isn't allowed to use the same object.

Comment: Do you have access to the code firing the event?

Comment: Do you have 3 in flight calls at the same time or are they non-overlapping?

Comment: @mot The result should be different yes. I may not have been very clear so I edited the question consequently.

Comment: @mikez The three calls are in the same time. The 3 responses arrive later and e matches the infoVersion value only the first time getInfoCompleted is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha thats a cute one. The first event that fires calls the handler for all 3 calls and removes their event registration, which makes the other ones not arrive.

To solve this, you can create a client for each call so the events won't intersect with each other.

A better solution would be using an async API that will recieve a callback for each call. If this is an automatically generated proxy class you can make it generate these kinds of methods.

Note: This requires .Net 4.5

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it answers the problem. However the "generate task-based operations" option is not available with Framework 4.0. I had to change the target Framework to 4.5.

Comment: Yep important note there. The async-await based api should be much sweeter and less prone to memory leaks.